# T-SQL - Pivot out Distinct N rows for each group

Tags: sql, select, pivot

I have a table similar to the one below with customers, products, and purchase date. I am trying to get a list of customers and their 3 most recently purchased DISTINCT products. I want to use purchase date as a means of ordering the results, but I don't want to see duplicate product IDs.

| Customer | Product | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2020-12-5 |
| 2 | b | 2020-12-5 |
| 1 | a | 2020-12-4 |
| 2 | a | 2020-12-3 |
| 1 | b | 2020-12-2 |
| 2 | b | 2020-12-1 |
| 1 | c | 2020-11-30 |
| 1 | d | 2020-11-29 |
| 2 | b | 2020-11-28 |

Ideally I would see results like this

| Customer | Product1 | Product2 | Product3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c |
| 2 | b | a |  |

I have tried partition by statements and order by statements, but everything wants me to include date in the final output. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most recent *distinct* products is tricky.  This requires one level of aggregation per customer and product and then another for pivoting:

```
select customer,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then product end) as product_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then product end) as product_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then product end) as product_3
from (select customer, product, max(purchasedate) as max_purchasedate,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by max(purchasedate) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by customer, product
     ) cp
group by customer;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm and is going to save us a lot of time.